# convert local image to base64 data

Tags: javascript, html, image, input

HTML code

```
<input id="file-input" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" type="file" name="name" />
```

after selecting the image , I run this code

```
var file = $("#file-input").val();
console.log(getBase64(file));
```

here's the getBase64 function

```
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

this function fires this error :

> Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not
>   of type 'Blob'.

that's what I tried - if you have workable answer = please share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`var file = $("#file-input").val();`

to

`var file = $("#file-input")[0].files[0];`

`.val()` is not actually returning the blob/file object that you want in this case.